# one column of my python data frame contains xml formatted data: how can I parse it?

Tags: python, xml

I have an xlsx dataset, one column of which is in xml. I loaded it in a data frame in python. Therefore one column of my data frame has xml entries. I would like to parse that column so that each xml variable is a different column in my data frame. I am not a data formatting expert and have tried to produce this outcome without success for hours, copying bits and pieces of codes I could find on stack overflow. 
So any help would be really appreciated.
One thing is that I need all the code to be in python, that's why I am not trying to modify the xlsx dataset directly.

**More details on the data:**
This data references different leads for a company. Each line has information on the individual lead. Several columns of the data frame are properly formatted (they have string or data entries) and one of the columns contains xml information.
One example for one lead of the xml info of the xml_result column is below. What I would like to extract is all the information that is in `<demande>...</demande>`, one column in my data frame per variable (example here I would like one column for `LOGIN`, one for `MDP`,..., one for `REQ_NAME_1`. etc).
Note that for each lead there can be a different amount of information in `<demande>` (for instance there could be a REQ_NAME_2 for another lead).

So what I have now is one column where a typical row has the following information:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<pisteAuditProfilingQualif>
  <resultat>
    <typeProfilQualif>Profil Standard (2)</typeProfilQualif>
  </resultat>
  <controles>
    <controle>
      <typeControle>Taux d'endettement après si hypo (4)</typeControle>
      <typeProfilQualif>Profil Prioritaire (1)</typeProfilQualif>
    </controle>
  </controles>
  <demande>
    <LOGIN>BOI</LOGIN>
    <MDP>BOI_ws2010</MDP>
    <AG_ID>7</AG_ID>
    <overflow>1</overflow>
    <PRT_ID>818</PRT_ID>
    <REQ_TITLE_1>Mademoiselle</REQ_TITLE_1>
    <REQ_NAME_1>Test</REQ_NAME_1>
  </demande>
</pisteAuditProfilingQualif>
```

and I would like a final row of my dataframe to have as many columns as variables in demande. For example here:

```py
LOGIN  MDP        AG_ID overflow PRT_ID REQ_TITLE_1   EMP_ID_CIVILITE REQ_NAME_1
BOI    BOI_ws2010  7    1        818    Mademoiselle  2               Test
```

Comment: You could import lxml and write a custom function which you could apply to the column.

Comment: This question could be improved by including an example of what you've already done, and a clearer example of what you want to see when you're finished.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to import etree but I am having a hard time parsing the column with it. Indeed all the examples I find of previous functions are parsing a .xml file and so when I try to apply it to my data frame column I am getting errors like " a bytes-like object is required, not 'Series' "

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question to make what the final output should be clearer. My past attempts with etree at making this work have been quite unsuccessful, I am not sure what I did will help anyone figure out the correct solution unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use ElementTree.fromstring to parse the xml in the dataframe, then Element.iter() to iterate over the children of 'demande', lastly join the new dataframe with the old.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml1 = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
            <pisteAuditProfilingQualif>
              ...
              <demande>
                ...
              </demande>
            </pisteAuditProfilingQualif>"""


xml2 = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
            ...
              <demande>
                ...
                <REQ_TITLE_2>Sirrah!</REQ_TITLE_2>
                <REQ_NAME_2>George</REQ_NAME_2>
              </demande>
            </pisteAuditProfilingQualif>"""

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[42, 54],'xml':[xml1, xml2]})

dfx = pd.DataFrame()
for x in df.xml:
    ex = ET.fromstring(x)
    ed = ex.find('demande')
    dfx = dfx.append(dict([(e.tag, e.text) for e in ed.iter()]), ignore_index=True)

print(df.join(dfx))

    a                                                xml  ... REQ_NAME_2 REQ_TITLE_2
0  42  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>\n ...  ...        NaN         NaN
1  54  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>\n ...  ...     George     Sirrah!

[2 rows x 12 columns]
```